# Merging two JSON files with common key values when there are other objects in the file

Tags: json, merge, jq

I have two JSON files I'm trying to merge, one is here:

File 1:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zcreativelabs/react-simple-maps/master/topojson-maps/world-110m.json

File 2:

https://gist.github.com/ArchieHicklin/764812b232a6cdc157d50da40bc033a5

File 1 begins with a topology object and array and a lot of stuff that can be ignored:

```
{
"type": "Topology",
"arcs": [
    [
        [16814, 15074],
        [71, -45],
        [53, 16],
        [15, 54],
        [55, 18],
        [39, 37],
        [14, 95],
        [59, 24],
        [11, 42],
        [32, -32],
        [21, -3]
    ],
```

...

Then goes into an array of countries (this is the part I want to add values to):

```
"objects": {
    "ne_110m_admin_0_countries": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [{
            "arcs": [
                [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            ],
            "type": "Polygon",
            "properties": {
                "NAME": "Afghanistan",
                "NAME_LONG": "Afghanistan",
                "ABBREV": "Afg.",
                "FORMAL_EN": "Islamic State of Afghanistan",
                "POP_EST": 34124811,
                "POP_RANK": 15,
                "GDP_MD_EST": 64080,
                "POP_YEAR": 2017,
                "GDP_YEAR": 2016,
                "ISO_A2": "AF",
                "ISO_A3": "AFG",
                "CONTINENT": "Asia",
                "REGION_UN": "Asia",
                "SUBREGION": "Southern Asia"
            }
        },
```

File 2 has an array of the same countries but with additional values:

```
{ "NAME": "Afghanistan", "BRANDONE": "Xiaomi", "BRANDTWO": "Apple", "BRANDTHREE": "Huawei", "BRANDFOUR": "Unknown", "BRANDFIVE": "Samsung", "BRANDSIX": "Oppo" },
```

As you can see the common value key between File 1 and File 2 is "NAME".

Ideally I'd like to merge the files so the original file includes the extra values from the other file eg:

```
"objects": {
"ne_110m_admin_0_countries": {
    "type": "GeometryCollection",
    "geometries": [{
        "arcs": [
            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon",
        "properties": {
            "NAME": "Afghanistan",
            "NAME_LONG": "Afghanistan",
            "ABBREV": "Afg.",
            "FORMAL_EN": "Islamic State of Afghanistan",
            "POP_EST": 34124811,
            "POP_RANK": 15,
            "GDP_MD_EST": 64080,
            "POP_YEAR": 2017,
            "GDP_YEAR": 2016,
            "ISO_A2": "AF",
            "ISO_A3": "AFG",
            "CONTINENT": "Asia",
            "REGION_UN": "Asia",
            "SUBREGION": "Southern Asia",
            "BRANDONE": "Xiaomi", 
            "BRANDTWO": "Apple", 
            "BRANDTHREE": "Huawei", 
            "BRANDFOUR": "Unknown", 
            "BRANDFIVE": "Samsung", 
            "BRANDSIX": "Oppo"
        }
    },
```

I've tried lots of merge answers on here but when I merge

(such as `jq -s '[ .[0] + .[1] | group_by(.NAME)[] | select(length > 1) | add ]' clean.json world.json`)

But I always end up with an error:

`jq: error (at file2.json:13575): array ([{"NAME":"A...) and object ({"type":"To...) cannot be added`

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is achievable in jq? And why do I always get an error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First construct a dictionary, and then use it to perform the update:

```
jq --argfile new 2.json '
 ($new | INDEX(.NAME)) as $dict
 | .objects.ne_110m_admin_0_countries.geometries[].properties
     |= (if $dict[.NAME] then . + $dict[.NAME] else . end)
' 1.json
```

### Incidentally ...

The hardest part here was determining the relevant path.  jq came to the rescue:

```
jq -c 'paths(. == "Afghanistan")' 1.json
```

Another possibility would have been to blindly update every value associated with "properties":

```
($new | INDEX(.NAME)) as $dict
| walk(if type == "object" and .properties
       then .properties |= . + $dict[.NAME]
       else . end)
```

This actually produces the same result.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much.