# Merging two json files with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json files:

File1:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "serviceName",
      "owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    }
]
```

and File2:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Nicole",
      "email": "nicole@email.com"
    }
]
```

I would like to have them merged like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "serviceName",
      "owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Nicole",
        "email": "nicole@email.com"
      }
    }
]
```

I'm trying the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234659/merging-two-json-files-with-common-key-values-when-there-are-other-objects-in-th) and try to use the following:

```
jq --argfile new file2.json '
 ($new | INDEX(.ID)) as $dict
 | .owner
     |= (if $dict[.ID] then . + $dict[.ID] else . end)
' file1.json
```

But that just results in an error.

Can anyone maybe provide me with some tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach fails because of the followings:

- Field names are case-sensitive. Having `{"id": 1}`, use `.id`, not `.ID`.
- Field names are strings. Having `{"id": 1}` and `INDEX(.id) as $dict`, use `$dict[.id | tostring]` or `$dict[.id | @text]` or `$dict["\(.id)"]` to convert the number `1` into the string `"1"` in the object index.
- Your files contain arrays. While `INDEX` defaults to read `.[]` from `file2.json`, you need to do it for `file1.json` yourself.

```bash
jq --argfile new file2.json '
  ($new | INDEX(.id)) as $dict | .[].owner |= (
    if $dict[.id | @text] then . + $dict[.id | @text] else . end
  )
' file1.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "serviceName",
    "owner": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Nicole",
      "email": "nicole@email.com"
    }
  }
]
```

---

As a suggestion, you could also employ `JOIN` to merge on a given key:

```bash
jq '
  JOIN(
    INDEX(input[]; .id); .[]; .id | @text; .[0].owner += .[1] | .[0]
  )
' file1.json file2.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "serviceName",
    "owner": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Nicole",
      "email": "nicole@email.com"
    }
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PiHkuEw5VXw)